# Retrieve files from t a folder on the basis of data

Tags: python-3.x

I have a folder which has log files from June to now. I want to retrieve files created in the last week of August and store them at a different path. I can get the creation date from the filename which is in this format:
 Run_Merge_BJDSBC_20190901-093

I want to code this in python, so  far I have reached here:

```
for filename in glob.glob(r"C:\Users\chke01\Desktop\PentahoLogs\BAF\*201908[0-9]*.log"):
```

But I dont know how to select these filenames and write to another folder. Can someone help me here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`glob.glob('path')` gives you a list of files. You can iterate over that list and use the `shutil` module to move and rename the files.

```py
for file in glob.glob('*'):
    shutil.move(file, new_folder_path)
```